# issue with Unpivot

Tags: sql, oracle

Unpivot failing while selecting all columns

the one which works,

```
SELECT
b.*
FROM   test b
UNPIVOT (amt FOR account IN (quantity AS 'Qty ',revenue AS 'Revenue',unit_price as 'Unit Price'))b
```

The below one fails,

```
select
all columns
from test b
UNPIVOT (amt FOR account IN (quantity AS 'Qty ',revenue AS 'Revenue',unit_price as 'Unit Price'))b
```

any reason why it wouldn't work when I select all the columns?

Comment: what is `all columns`?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the exact error message you get. It would also help if you show us what you are trying to do by adding some [sample data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). (please [edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 0):

"all columns" is syntax that is unknown to Oracle. The way to get all possible columns is "*".

You are using B as an alias for the TEST table and for the result of the UNPIVOT clause. This confuses the issue.

In fact, the columns in the TEST table are not available for SELECTion. The only columns you can SELECT are the ones that exist after the UNPIVOT operation. Try this:

```
select a.* from dual a
unpivot(val for col in (dummy));

Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "A": invalid identifier
```

The table is input to UNPIVOT, that is all.